# No headphones sound in Asus U52F laptop

Tags: 11.10, sound, kubuntu, headphones

I have no sound in kubuntu even in 11.04 and now in 11.10 the same problem. My laptop is Asus U52F. I have tried all, no idea what to do now.

lspci |grep -i audio returns:

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to do some super sneaky stuff, but it eventually will work. The first step is to make sure that `Alsa` is installed. Then open file

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

At the bottom of the page paste in a new line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Save and restart! It should work fine after that. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same model laptop running Ubuntu 11.10. The above answer does work. As a side note I use a usb wireless mouse that when I have it plugged in and restart it sound doesn't work. If I take it out and restart it the sound works. It is the weirdest thing but if the above answer doesn't work for you and you have usb items plugged in remove them asd see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**"I have tried all..."**

Well - I only can offer links, maybe these are familiar to you or maybe not.

The Kubuntu Forums has "Top 20 Kubuntu FAQs & Answers" ( http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3099811.0 ) number 6 is "No Audio".

Comment: Tried that, did not worked :-(